# Error: there is no package called ‘purrr' -- but 'purrr' isn't in my code anywhere?

Tags: r, package, purrr

I'm pretty new to R but hopefully I can provide enough info here!

I was working on a project in R and someone recommended to me to use a package called "purrr." I tried to install it, and it said "purrr" doesn't exist. It does not show up as installed in my package library. I have removed the line calling to install purrr in my code and also cleared all my objects from the workspace. I have closed RStudio and reopened it. But whenever I try to call any package using the `library()` function, I am shown an error.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘googlesheets’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘purrr’

Has something like this happened to anyone else? How can I fix this?

Comment: Package `googlesheets` depends on the `purrr` package, so you need both to be installed even if you're only using the former. Try reinstalling `purrr` again and see if you can use `googlesheets`. If that doesn't work, edit your question to provide the output of `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Look at imports and suggests part: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/googlesheets.pdf Install `purrr`